# HTTP Basic Auth with Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, basic-authentication

I need to access a Maven repo which requires HTTP Basic Auth (no https).
Is there a way to configure the HTTP headers from the pom.xml (or anywhere in the project) directly?
I do not want to modify the settings.xml, since that would lead to structural changes in our deployment process.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: But the location is the settings.xml and not the pom apart from that you can't configure it in the pom file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an Artifactory/Maven Repo that requires basic-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280747/accessing-an-artifactory-maven-repo-that-requires-basic-auth)