# Setting system-wide/global proxy in java

Tags: java, proxy

I am currently working on a local proxyserver in Java, now to prevent any work for the user I want to set the system-wide proxy settings to the local proxy server using my code.

I tried using;

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "10001");

System.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
```

But if I am correct these are just the settings for the JVM?

How can I achieve setting a system-wide proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was different for each platform, I currently only implemented the proxy settings on Windows and OSX.

- Modify the preferences.plist file on OSX, this is the file located at

> /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

- Modify the registry on Windows, editing the following path

> Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

Comment: for linux/Solaris or any platform you could just use `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable as explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2966629/1503505