# How to make maven use system proxy settings

Tags: maven-2

I'm using Ubuntu with Gnome where I can set network proxy settings (with authentication).

The question is: how I can run maven in command line and make it use this proxy?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a `java.net.useSystemProxies` system property  that can be set to `true` (on Windows and Linux platforms) to tell the JVM to use the system proxy settings. From the [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) guide:

> Before we see in details how to write such a `ProxySelector`, let's talk about the default one. J2SE 5.0 provides a default implementation which enforces backward compatibility. In other terms, the default `ProxySelector` will check the system properties described earlier to determine which proxy to use. However, there is a new, optional feature: On recent Windows systems and on Gnome 2.x platforms it is possible to tell the default `ProxySelector` to use the system proxy settings (both recent versions of Windows and Gnome 2.x let you set proxies globally through their user interface). If the system property `java.net.useSystemProxies` is set to `true` (by default it is set to `false` for compatibility sake), then the default `ProxySelector` will try to use these settings. You can set that system property on the command line, or you can edit the JRE installation file `lib/net.properties`, that way you have to change it only once on a given system.

But this will only work for the `java.net.*` classes, not for commons-httpclient, jsch, etc. So this doesn't solve the whole issue and Maven doesn't really support it (this is logged as [MNG-728](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-728)).

In other words, I'm afraid you'll have to configure the proxy settings in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`.

Answer (score 34):

Did you take a look at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html?

In your settings.xml:

```
<settings>
  .
  .
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
  .
</settings>
```

NOTE: This doesn't affect Java code!  These proxy settings are Maven repository proxy settings.

Comment: always remember to check $home/.m2/settings.xml and $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml, I took about half hour to disable proxy because it was enabled in the maven binaries folder

Comment: You might have to create the file if it doesn't exist already

Comment: user name and password is not compulsory.

Comment: Keep in mind, _won't work_ with NTLM proxies though.

Comment: this fixed it for me.

Comment: As @Iwpro2 says, took me a while to figure out: username and password not compulsory!!

Comment: FYI for containers running as root the home folder is /root

Answer (score 8):

Those who need to set these settings through the command line can use the following:

```
MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=yourProxyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort=9999 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=mvnrepository.com"
```

Usage:

```
mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
```

Warning: 
nonProxyHosts property did not work correctly for me when using it from a CI environment. I suspect it might be because the pipe characters are not being interpreted correctly in Gitlab's YAML syntax but I didn't find a way to fix that.

Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/java-option-http-nonproxyhosts-does-not-work-214863640.html

Comment: As I have to use an NTLM proxy in an enterprise, this is the only suggestion that works for me that is somewhat succinct. Gradle opts works seamlessly.

Comment: If you use `MAVEN_OPTS` variable instead, you don't need to pass it explicitly to `mvn` command as it is used automatically.

Comment: Didn't work for me but settings.xml worked

Comment: Had to use `-Dhttps.` versions of the same set of parameters (because indeed it was connecting via HTTPS) 
Worked for me on linux, JRE8, mvn 3.6.3

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans youhave to remove the `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` from `Tools-> option->java->Maven`. Once you remove it, Maven reads the proxy settings from `settings.xml`.