# Not able to create a new maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I try to create new Maven project from eclipse it is throwing an error "Could not resolve archetype".[image]

My java version: "1.8.0_162"
MY Maven Version: apache-maven-3.3.9
So , please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

```
1. Open Window > Preferences
2. Open Maven > Archetypes
3. Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:
    Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
    Description: maven catalog
```

Comment: Please also explain what you think is the cause and what's the idea behind your solution! :-)

Comment: I followed your steps , but it is saying "Remote Catalog" is empty

Comment: Are you able to get to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml using your browser. This will help determine if it is a firewall problem

Comment: No,I can't reach the site, it is taking much time to load and saying page unresponsive, I tried multiple time and every time it is same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25807975/8098322 try this answer

Answer (score 0):

Sometime work-space gets corrupted and the catalog gets missing, You can fix this by adding new catalog or by changing your work space to a new drive.

1. Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Maven ->Archetype
2. Click on Add Remote Catalog
3. Add catalogue file as
   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml Description as
   Remote Archetype catalogue
4. Click on Verify, you should see a message like Found XXX archetype’s

> If you are behind a proxy you might need to go to Windows ->
>   Preference-> Network and add the proxy details

**Possible Solution:** [Create a Maven project in Eclipse complains "Could not resolve archetype"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype)

Comment: I' am facing this issue in my company machine, so assuming I' am behind proxy but how to confirm we are behind a proxy or not

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601474/how-to-make-maven-use-system-proxy-settings