# Maven Could not resolve dependencies, artifacts could not be resolved

Tags: maven, maven-3

This is supposed to be a working project from my friend.  He demonstrated the project right in front of me, and then I copied the project, imported it as an existing maven project (I'm using `m2eclipse` plugin).

And then, this error occurs. This error can be reproduced every time I try to build something with maven.

Doing mvn dependency:tree, dependency:list, or the usual build package, will result in the same error.

The error from running the 'package' build from eclipse is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Jackpot Portal Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for javax.servlet:com.springsource.javax.servlet:jar:2.5.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for javax.servlet:com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for javax.transaction:com.springsource.javax.transaction:jar:1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.slf4j:com.springsource.slf4j.log4j:jar:1.5.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.963s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 11 01:55:41 WIT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jackpot: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project com.jeteo:jackpot:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could 
not be resolved: javax.servlet:com.springsource.javax.servlet:jar:2.5.0,
javax.servlet:com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.0, 
javax.transaction:com.springsource.javax.transaction:jar:1.1.0, 
org.slf4j:com.springsource.slf4j.log4j:jar:1.5.6: Failure to find 
javax.servlet:com.springsource.javax.servlet:jar:2.5.0 in 
http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in the 
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of com.springsource.repository.bundles.release has elapsed or 
updates are forced -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

And here is the content of the `pom.xml` :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jeteo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackpot</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Jackpot Portal Webapp</name>
    <url>http://www.jeteo.com</url>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.hibernate-version>3.6.0.Final</org.hibernate-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.persistence</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.transaction</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.slf4j.log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.11</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <!-- Spring releases -->
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Repository Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- For hibernate 3.6 support -->
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>jackpot</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've tried downloading the newest version of maven, and included it in the eclipse helios, but still the same problem. The same error message happens even when I run it it in the shell command line (outside eclipse).

**What am I missing?**

Comment: see your path in system variable.In my case the path for maven 3 was correct in user variable but after changing the path to maven 2 in system variable it was working fine.no idea why

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some Maven repos. Ask for your friend's `.m2/settings.xml`, and you'll probably want to update the POM to include the repositories there.

--edit: after some quick googling, try adding this to your POM:

```
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
    <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
    <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Thank you ! My friend mentioned that it worked in his laptop because he already got the dependencies cached in the .m2/ and maven doesnt try to download them anymore. And he shared the repository entries, some are like your finding, and now it worked fine now .. Thank you for your time ! And if i may know, what keywords do you use to find out what repositories to use ? I tried googling also yesterday, but i ended up miserable. haha

Comment: I knew it was a repository problem because of the "POM for xxx is missing" warning messages. So I just searched on "springsource maven" and came up with the springsource project FAQ, and its entry for setting it up to work with Maven.

Comment: His first artifact error is a provided jar com.springsource.javax.servlet. If it's provided why would it have anything to do with setting.xml?

Comment: @PhilipRego `.m2/settings.xml` can specify repository listings outside of the standard ones at `repo.maven.apache.org`. In this case, the JARs are coming from a SpringSource repository and are not on Maven Central. I had assumed that the friend had the SpringSource repos listed in local `.m2/settings.xml`, causing no lookup errors because the artifacts would be found in alternate maven repos. Instead, the JARs were cached, and no lookups happened at all.

Comment: But why is it connecting to the internet at all for a provided dependency? Maven says about provided: "expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime". If the dependency is in the JDK or container why would it try to connect to a repository?

Comment: @PhilipRego These dependencies are not marked as provided. Even if the dependency is provided, the interface definitions are required to compile the code; that means you must have the JAR files defining the interfaces used. All it means for a provided dependency is the JARs are not packaged with your code.

Answer (score 44):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Solved my problem. Since the repos were cached, I needed to force it to get latest version.

Answer (score 20):

Maven kept your files on cache, and don't retry to download them. You can simply manually 'help' him by deleting the `repository` directory from your `.m2` directory, and then our friend will download everything over the old dependencies.

Comment: I think it should be `repository` directory, not whole `.m2` where may be stored files like `settings.xml`

Answer (score 9):

The `artifactId` for all the dependencies that failed to download are incorrect - for some reason they are prefixed with `com.springsource`.  Cut/paste issue?

You can try replacing them as follows.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You may also want to add the maven central repository for these artifacts in case they are not available in the specified repositories.

```xml
<repository>
    <id>maven2</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: I tried that, and still errornous ? Here's the partial output from eclipse after doing a package task : Failed to execute goal on project jackpot: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.jeteo:jackpot:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5.0, javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2.0, javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1.0: Failure to find javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5.0 in http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of <cutted>....

Comment: @Albert Kam.  Updated answer to include reference to maven central repository for the missing artifacts

Comment: com.springsource prefix means the artifacts are coming from spring enterprise repository

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative source to the same problem, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11018601/3708977) cites using Maven 3 versus Maven 2 as the potential cause of this issue. Near as I can tell, this is due to changes in [local repository resolution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-ResolutionfromLocalRepository) that was changed in Maven 3. Putting this here in case anyone else googles for it and reaches this answer (as I did).

Answer (score 8):

Download the jar manually and then execute the command from the folder where the jar is saved:

> ```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=*jar_file_name*.jar-DgroupId=*group_id* -DartifactId=*artifact_id* -Dversion=*version_no* -Dpackaging=jar
> ```

The `jar file`, `jar_file_name`, `group_id`, `artifact_id` and `version_no` are available from the maven repository page.

Answer (score 4):

I have had a similar problem and I fixed it by adding the below repos in my pom.xml:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
    <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-local</url>
    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
<!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
<repository>
    <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
    <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
<!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
<repository>
    <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone-local</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to run

`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install -U`

This solved a similar issue that I faced.
Lots more info available at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html.
This answer was taken and adapted from a previous answer on a related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33929792/5538923 .

In addition, since I am working under a proxy to connect to internet in Windows, although setting the environment variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY, I had also to set them in the settings.xml file of maven:

```xml
<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>httpproxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>your-proxy-host</host>
        <port>your-proxy-port</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
        <id>httpsproxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <host>your-proxy-host</host>
        <port>your-proxy-port</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </proxy>

  </proxies>
</settings>
```

This last configuration has been adapted from another answer in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13958845/5538923. See details about setting the proxy configuration in Maven here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html. Other users found success specify the proxy for Maven setting another environment variable (in Windows) such as (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46244884/5538923):

```
MAVEN_OPTS
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.myproxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.myproxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80
```

To me, however, it worked by just settings those values in the C:/Users/myUser/.m2/settings.xml file.

Comment: This issue could be happening for multiple reasons! One of such reason is listed here FYI which I solved using this answer: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/13127

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problems are caused by two reasons:

1. the spell of a dependency is wrong
2. the config of mvn setting (ie. ~/.m2/settings.xml) is wrong

If most of dependencies can be downloaded, then the reason 1 may be the most likely bug.
On the contrary, if most of dependencies have the problem, then u should take a look at **settings.xml**.

Well, I have tried to fix my problem the whole afternoon, and finally I got it. My problem occurs in settings.xml, not the lose or wrong spelling of **settings.xml**, but the lose of [**activeProfiles**](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Active_Profiles).

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar message and my problem were some proxy preferences in my settings.xml.
So i disabled them and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, however I fixed this issue by placing `settings.xml` file in `.m2` folder . This is the exact path where I had placed my settings.xml file `C:/Users/myUser/.m2/settings.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  In my case it was caused by IntelliJ Idea messing around with some of the pom.xml files (which it seems to enjoy doing!).  I just reverted to the original copy and things worked again!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, it turned out it was because of NetBeans adding something to my pom.xml file. Double check nothing was added since previous successful deployments.

Answer (score 0):

My EAR project had 2 modules *.ear and *.war and I got this dependency error on `*.war` project when trying `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Resolved it by fixing utf-8 encoding issue in the `*.war` project. `mvn` `-X` or `-e` options weren't of help here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it happened because of the firewall on my computer. Turning it off worked for me.

Comment: While turning off the firewall on your computer might work, depending on your network setup I would recommend searching for a more secure solution e.g. by adding an exception for the maven process or maven central... Sounds like a misconfigured/very strict firewall setup to me though

Comment: @Capricorn right, this is not the best but for me I tried all the solutions recommended and It just works fine on this. If you have any better solution, please tell me,  thank you !!!

editted: you mentioned "adding an exception for the maven process or maven central", I don't really get it, can you specify these ...

Answer (score 0):

Have come across such issue. The root cause is the .m2 folder.
You gotta make sure that whatever you're trying to access is present there in your .m2 folder (this is your local repo). If the stuff is there then you're good.
This is usually present inside of users folder on your system (be it mac/linux or even windows)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete or cut the settings.xml file from C:/Users/username/.m2/
folder and it will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to wrong maven repository getting referred for finding artifacts. Seems, my company has its own repository which needs to be referred for fetching all artifacts and dependencies. Adding link to company hosted server in my **settings.xml** inside **.m2 folder** fixed the issue.

```
 <mirrors>
  <mirror> <!--Send all requests to the public group -->
   <id>{{COMPANY_SERVER_ID}}</id>
   <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
   <url>{{COMPANY_SELF_HOSTED_REPO_URL}}</url>
  </mirror>
 </mirrors>
```