# NoClassDefFoundError with Spring maven hibernate org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven, pom.xml

spring3 jpa(hibernate) for my project but im having problems with the Hibernate Persistence class ... so I cant create properly my entityManager and the problem goes on and on ...

I belive the problem its in my pom.xml file! (if its not the problem then perhaps in my applicationCOntext.xml? dont think so but ho knows...)

here its the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.divux</groupId>
<artifactId>OneX</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>OneX</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
   <!-- Shared version number properties -->

<!--Core utilities used by other modules.
Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans)
This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always 
Defined-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration
Define this if you need any of these integrations-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy(org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <!-- <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> -->
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNGThis artifact is generally always 
Defined with a 'test' scope for the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

            <!-- JUnit test  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

            <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

            <!-- JPA with Hibernate Persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-cr-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>    

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/resources/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And now the error output:

```
04-ene-2012 17:23:49 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatchermaven'
04-ene-2012 17:23:50 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'DAOPersonImp': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:     Cannot create inner bean     'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#1b9bbe8' of type     [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property     'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#1b9bbe8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean         with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-    INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean         'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#1b9bbe8' of type     [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property     'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#1b9bbe8' defined in     ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;     nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean     with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#1b9bbe8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not     instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]:         Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
... 56 more
04-ene-2012 17:23:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: El Servlet /OneX-1 lanzó excepción de load()
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

04-ene-2012 17:23:55 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatchermaven'
04-ene-2012 17:23:55 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name         'DAOPersonImp': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is         org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:             Cannot create inner bean     'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#a877c0' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#a877c0' defined in     ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;     nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]:     Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean     with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-    INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean     'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#a877c0' of type     [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#a877c0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;     nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not     instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#a877c0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence

04-ene-2012 17:23:55 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Excepción de reserva de espacio para servlet dispatchermaven
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>    (HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:98)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findNamedEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:510)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
```

You can see its a nested error ... I think its all because the problem with the HibernatePersistence class ... As you can see i have a LOT of dependencys in my pom.xml ... thats the result of trying unsuccessfuly ..

Hope you guys can help me! Let me know if there is something more you need.
(I just delete some of the error content for the characters limit ... nothing important i hope hehe)

Comment: try changing dependency jars versions by referring to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.3.2.GA

Comment: You should just need hibernate-entitymanager. The required jars such as hiberate-core etc. should be pulled in automatically as required dependencies.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The class `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` is missing. It is part of `hibernate-entity-manger-<version>.jar`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW you mixed the versions of the different hibenate jars in a not recommended way. Use the same version for all the strong related hibernate packages  (Hibernate validation is somehing different).

An example:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.6.7.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

...

<!-- Persistance -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

### For me, it was not enough

I had the same problem, it happened when I launched a test in IntelliJ. I found all receipts: I added hibernate-entitymanager, as is advised here, I checked for overlapping hibernate-jpa and exclude them. I added spring-orm, as advises [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427271/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-ejb-hibernatepersistence/40557631) answers on SO. And I still got the same error. I checked all 20 poms of the project for overlapped packages and for versions of packages, too.

I refreshed the maven repository by

```
mvn -e clean install -U
```

, as is advised in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9697970/715269 - so old and upvoted answer, that I see it as Santa.

The problem remained unchanged.

I output the maven map. It was correct and it contained all needed.

I looked at the list of the `External Libraries` of the project. It was the old shitty list of overlapping jars with same names and different versions, and without good packages I added just now, and well seen in maven tree output!

Already hapless,

### I reimported packages in IntelliJ

by:

```
Ctrl+Shift+A, Reimport All Maven Projects.
```

Ho! The list of libraries got repaired. And the problem, mentioned in subj, disappeared.