# problems configuring Spring + JPA/Hibernate: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.Hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I want to use Spring 3.2.8 + JPA/Hibernate on Oracle DB (first time for me).

I think I can not configure correctly something (persistence unit, spring config files) so i have always an error when deploying in Tomcat.

```
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.Hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:288)
    ... 38 more

Aug 08, 2014 1:37:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 08, 2014 1:37:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ftc-wo-webapp] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 08, 2014 1:37:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 08, 2014 1:37:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

The hibernate jars (including entity manager jar) are contained in the final war (under WEB-INF/lib) So I don't understand why still the class is not founded.
The following configuration is present:

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="woBPFlowInfo">
    <provider>org.Hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

main spring config file: app_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
      ...    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ftc.webapp" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Database added -->

    <!-- Loads BPFlowInfo from the JPA system -->
    <bean id="woBPFlowRepository" class="com.ftc.webapp.data.JpaWoBPFlowRepository"/>

    <!-- Instructs the container to look for beans with @Transactional and decorate them -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Enables annotation-config, needed for @PersistenceContext annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config />

     <import resource="db_config.xml"/>
</beans>
```

db_config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- // NAME: rewards-db-config.xml // // MODULE: rewardsdb // // PURPOSE: 
    Database and transaction configuration for testing the rewards // application. -->
<beans xmlns="...">

    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Translates ORM exceptions to Spring Data Access Exceptions -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <!-- Data access using 100% JPA -->
        <!-- A transaction manager for working with JPA Entity Managers -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>

        <!-- FactoryBean that creates the EntityManagerFactory -->
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="woBPFlowInfo" />
        </bean>
</beans>
```

and pom.xml contains  following dependencies:

pom.xml

```
  <properties>
      <smp.version>5.2.2.6</smp.version>
      <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
      <hibernate.version>3.4.0.GA</hibernate.version>
      <javaxServlet.version>2.5</javaxServlet.version>
      <jackson.version>1.9.5</jackson.version>      
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaxServlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Persistency & Object Relational mapping -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734962/noclassdeffounderror-with-spring-maven-hibernate-org-hibernate-ejb-hibernatepers ?

Comment: well this doesn't help. As mentioned there I need only hibernate-entitymanager as dependency (from hibernate) I changed the version to 4.2.8.Final from 3.4.0.GA so that hibernate-core has the same version as hibernate=entitymanager, I removed dependency to spring-data-jpa and introduced dep. to spring-tx & spring-orm as in other examples I have. Still doesn't help. If i have the hibernate-enititymanager jar in the /WEB-INF/lib dir, why the class is not founded ?

Answer (score 2):

as I suspected - bad configuration, in fact bad spelling.
replace

```
<provider>org.Hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

with

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

and ClassNotFoundException: org.Hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence  disappear

Stupid enough. I spent lot's of hours for this stupid issue.
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>` is the right persistence provider as per JPA standards.

`<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` is deprecated.