# Unable to run springboot application , getting OptimisticLockException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**I am getting below error**

**error:**

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-03-16
>   22:15:18.779 ERROR 20486 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory
>   method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/OptimisticLockException
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   com.vl.cybersecurity.CyberSecurityApplication.main(CyberSecurityApplication.java:12)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.OptimisticLockException     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>     ... 61 common frames omitted

**My Pom.xml file:**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>vl</groupId>
<artifactId>CyberSecurity</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CyberSecurity</name>
<description>cybersecurity</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.57</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20171018</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError with Spring maven hibernate org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734962/noclassdeffounderror-with-spring-maven-hibernate-org-hibernate-ejb-hibernatepers)

Comment: @MehrajMalik I have added mavan dependency for hibernate-entitymanager in pom.xml file, still facing same issue

Comment: I dont think you need to define any hibernate-entitymanager here. Definitely you have a missing dependency and the pom you pasted looks ok. Can you paste/share the relevant code so it might be easier to understand why you have a DI issue and whats missing.

Comment: @Vangel this is huge proj , I can not send code here.. I am able to run same project in once machine successfully.. getting issue while going with another machine actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got solution for this. I have removed the maven repositories folder in and able to run maven project with springboot**

```
cd ~/.m2 
rm -rf repository/
```

Comment: well you last comment said it. Corrupted maven repo can have odd errors. Glad you sorted it and posted the answer as well. thank you