# Fix given in the dependency jar did not reflect even after mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a dependency jar in which there was a bug. Developer gave a fix.

Artifact version was not changed. So I just did a mvn clean install on my project. But It did not download the changes done for the artifact.

So, not sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: use the option -U to force the dependency update. also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update

Comment: "Artifact version was not changed" - if it is a fix version, it should have a new version number (unless it is a -SNAPSHOT version, where the -U fix applies)

Comment: It is SNAPSHOT version

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this from Console, then do a mvn clean.

```
find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -print -exec rm {} \;
```

Else, download the jar, and install it manually using maven, then clean it