# Dependencies are resolved only on my mac machine and not on the Windows one for the same project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a couple of dependencies that resolve when I use IntelliJ Idea with my mac machine but for some strange reason they cannot be resolved when I am running the same project with IntelliJ Idea again on my windows machine.

Here are the two dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opengamma.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>og-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opengamma.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>og-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I even tried to run mvn clean install on the project directory on the windows machine and the build stops with this error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.opengamma.platform:og-client:pom:2.1.0 is missing, no
dependency information available
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/opengamma/platform/og-serve
r/2.1.0/og-server-2.1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.opengamma.platform:og-server:pom:2.1.0 is missing, no
dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.611 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-26T22:03:08+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/115M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Project3: Could not resolve dependenci
es for project com.skiabox.apps:Project3:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifac
ts could not be resolved: com.opengamma.platform:og-client:pom:2.1.0, com.openga
mma.platform:og-server:pom:2.1.0: Failure to find com.opengamma.platform:og-clie
nt:pom:2.1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repo
sitory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central
has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
```

Comment: Relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9697970/1079354 (you may want to use the `-U` flag on Windows to force repositories to update).

Comment: I just tried it but I get the same error again.

Comment: Is it an option to manually copy the com.opengamma directory from one's computer .m2 to the other?

Comment: I copied the folder manually but for some reason I get the same error again.Can I force maven to look at the .m2 folder first?

Comment: I even tried mvn clean install -o but the error remains!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are looking for the OG dependencies in

- http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

However, OpenGamma currently does not put their dependencies there. Instead, try looking here:

- http://maven.opengamma.com/nexus/content/groups/public/

I added this to my top-level pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-opengamma</id>
        <name>Public online OpenGamma repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.opengamma.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Hope this helps.

Eric