# Maven Force Update Snapshot Dependencies

Tags: maven

Here is the result of mvn -version:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 00:44:56-0800)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_67, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Suppose I have a snapshot dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.puzzled</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a downloaded copy of that snapshot in my local repo. But then other developers have made improvements and there is an update to the foo-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar. I want to issue Maven an executive order to update that dependency by downloading it from a remote repository.

According to the response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update) and many other questions on SO, if I do

```
mvn clean -U package
```

it should just (re)download all the dependencies. Right? That is not what happens. It downloads metadata for snapshot dependencies, deduces (and wrongly, at that) that no updating is required. I have to delete the associated subdirectory in my local .m2 repository for Maven to update a snapshot release from the remote repo, even with the -U flag.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I never had this problem with maven 3.0.3 but started getting it in 3.2.3 just like you described. :-(

Comment: Just to check, you might want to at least try to copy out your local .m2 folder to save somewhere else and clear out the .m2 directory. Then try running a fresh install and see if it grabs the dependencies. This will just check to ensure that your settings are actually correct and you are hitting the right server for the artifacts in case you currently have all dependencies cached locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force maven update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update)

Comment: what do you mean by "I have a downloaded copy of that snapshot in my local repo" - downloaded by maven when doing the previous clean-install? or downloaded manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it possible that the repository is publishing your `foo` using a non-unique SNAPSHOT name?

This [blog entry](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/09/how-does-a-maven-repository-work/#unique-vs-non-unique-snapshots) explains nicely the difference between a unique and non-unique SNAPSHOT artifact.

Essentially, it's non-unique if the artifact metadata appears **on nexus** as `foo-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar`.  It's unique if it appears as `foo-1.0.4-20160122.172609-36.jar`.

You can *only* publish unique snapshot artifacts in Maven 3, but still resolve old timestamped non-unique snapshots... but it's pretty iffy.  Taking a look at the [ancient doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+-+SNAPSHOT+Handling), it seems that there's some unclear and vague interaction between the filesystem date, and the metadata.xml on both local and remote machines.

Essentially: (1) Try to make sure that your SNAPSHOT dependencies are published with unique artifacts, and (2) if they aren't, don't depend on new SNAPSHOTs being detected.  Use `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`   with appropriate includes to remove the old SNAPSHOTs from your local m2 instead.

Answer (score 11):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

-U means force update of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this shell script:

```sh
# Get path to local maven repo...
MVN_REPO=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository | grep -e '^/')

echo "Local Maven repository is here: $MVN_REPO"
 
# Remove SNAPSHOT versions in "com/github/myusername" sub directory...
find "$MVN_REPO/com/github/myusername" -name *-SNAPSHOT.jar -exec rm {} \;
```

It finds all jar files for a particular group id that end with `-SNAPSHOT.jar` in your local maven repo and deletes them.

The build afterwards can then be successfully triggered using:

```sh
mvn clean -U package
```

Maybe someone finds it useful.