# maven unable to resolve dependecies from local repository instead of fetching everytime from centralized repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

Our project structure is using maven multi module structure.

```
ParentApp
     - childApp1
           - pom.xml
           - other directories
     - childApp2
           - pom.xml
           - other directories
     pom.xml(parent directory contains only pom.xml file)
```

For the above structure we are having a centralized repository and maven tries to download all the dependencies and place it in local repository.
I am trying to restructure the project structure by removing childApp1 and placing it under a new maven project ParentApp2. I am trying to build childApp1 but it throws the exception

```
was cached in the local repository resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
```

This exception occurs because of restructure happens for childApp1, while trying to build childApp2 in parentApp1 it tries to fetch the dependency jar files from central repository. After removing the dependency in childApp1 pom.xml file it compiles. 
My question is after restructure maven plugin still tries to download it from central repository instead of fetching from local repository.
**Note:** I have tried by updating maven project by right click maven + update project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force maven update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add -U to the maven command line?