# Stuck in JBOSS Ticket Monster adding Arquillian

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I try to master Red Hat Ticket Monster 2.7 tutorial with JBOSS EAP 6.4.
I cant master Chapter 28.1 "Adding ShrinkWrap Resolvers".
First paragraph does not match POM.XML extract and changing to the "wfk" bom leads to an error in the project.

Here the Error:

Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer org.jboss.bom.wfk:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:2.7.0-
 redhat-1 from http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
 reattempted until the update interval of jboss-ga-repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
 artifact org.jboss.bom.wfk:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:2.7.0-redhat-1 from/to jboss-ga-repository (http://
 maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all): maven.repository.redhat.com: unknown error

Its on the first line of this part of the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.bom.wfk</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
    <version>${version.jboss.bom.wfk}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any idea???

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing Maven to check for updated dependencies.

```
mvn -U [<goal(s)>]
```

Check [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update) for alternative solutions.