# Build Failure Error “maven-compiler-plugin:3.3.9 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved”

Tags: eclipse, maven

Am creating new java project using the pom.xml file. when i run the command mvn clean install am getting build failure error.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.
[image]

and my pom.xml is like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>tasapitesting</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>tasapitesting</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>1.8</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update

Comment: I tried it but it didnt worked me...still am getting the same error

Comment: Not possible. The error HAS to be different when you're running Maven with the `-U` flag, and forces the updates...

Comment: am getting the same error. its not working for me.can anyone plz help me to resolve this issue

Comment: You won't get any help, if you're not responsive to the help you're getting.

Comment: @Tunaki ,you the can see the screenshot as am getting the same error even after tried with -U

Comment: I can't read the error message in the screenshot. Post it as **text**, and the **complete** one. But it sounds like you're behind a proxy, please configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Central doesn't seem to have a 3.3.9 build for maven-compiler-plugin (see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin)). Regardless, the 3.3 generation is quite old. Unless you absolutely, positively **have** to use such an old version, just move forward to a newer version that actually exists, like 3.6.0, and you should be fine.

Comment: Tried with 3.6.0 but it is not working still getting error like this :[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6 or one of its
dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:mav
en-compiler-plugin:jar:3.6 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in
 the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update inter
val of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: And in my local system maven installed is 3.3.9...is it because of this am getting this error. Thanks in advance,plz help me