# Local Nexus Server - Mirrors

Tags: maven, settings, nexus

I still get this error:

```
 [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin
:jar:2.6 in http://it-nexus.myDomain:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

and this has to do with this mirror configuration:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
     <id>nexus</id>
     <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
     <url>http://it-nexus.myDomain:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
     <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

It is not clear for me how to configure the mirrors in that way that I can upload my Artefacts with **mvn deploy**.

It seams to me that Maven looks up for plugin- artefacts at my plain Nexus- Server. In my opinion it should be cascaded in that way that if artefacts are not available in my local nexus that it should be looked up in central.
How to do that?

Comment: Did you do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately apparent to me what you need to do to solve this, however I felt like I'd share a working example from one of the guys on our team: https://github.com/dulanism/java-test/blob/master/pom.xml

You'll want to setup a profile similar to what Dulani has done in his pom.xml file. With that setup you can publish both releases and snapshots to a local Nexus Repository Manager.