# Why is my maven pointing to old central repository url?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am facing issue with downloading dependency jars through maven install.

From eclipse console, i can say maven is trying to download jars from old central repository url:"https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" instead of "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestServices</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.3.6</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And my build is failing with the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project 'xxxyyy': Could not resolve dependencies for project xxxyyy:jar:4.0.3.6: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus:xstream:jar:1.3.1, gxs:ai:jar:0.5, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.0.2, com.oracle.jdbc:classes12:jar:9.2.0.5, org.eclipse.core:resources:jar:3.1.0, org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.2.0.v20060603, org.eclipse.emf:common:jar:2.2.1.v200609210005, org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:2.2.1.v200609210005, org.eclipse.emf:ecore.xmi:jar:2.2.1.v200609210005, org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.2.0.v20060603, org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.2.1.R32x_v20060919, org.eclipse.wst.xml:core:jar:1.1.1.v200609210600, org.eclipse:xsd:jar:2.2.1.v200609210005, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.3.2, org.apache:log4j:jar:1.2.8: Failure to find org.codehaus:xstream:jar:1.3.1 in ${localRepo} was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of 'abcd' has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Can you show the pom.xml?

Comment: @Gatusko updated post

Comment: Updated answer Hope it helps you

Comment: Both URL are the same (well points to the same thing)... what is the issue? You just defined a custom repository `abcd` and "resolution will not be reattempted", so you can run Maven with `-U` flag.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
```

And check this documentation of [Maven Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)

And following the Documentation:

Repositories

> The repository is one of the most powerful features of the Maven
>   community. The default central Maven repository lives on
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/. Another source for artifacts
>   not yet in iBiblio is the Codehaus snapshots repo.

Maven Repositories Default [Doc](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories)

Comment: No.... this comes already [from the Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html)...

Comment: My bad the SEcond link of Doc was bad. Alrteady edited the link. I quoted from the documentation of Maven Repositories. But you are right

Comment: @Gatusko Now repo1.maven.org and repo.maven.apache.org need https: https://links.sonatype.com/central/501-https-required

Comment: Thanks @artscan I've already edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you have changed the repository address:

```
 <repositories>
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
```

You have to clean every previously cached data in your repository, neither manually or by running maven phases (e.g package) with -U option `package -U`

-U means force update of all dependencies.

Comment: How can we force update (-U) this in eclipse? (m2eclipse plugin)

Comment: here is how : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21598727/3593084