# Maven pom changes, aggregator builds and test runs on CI server

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration

I have an aggregator pom and two modules.

Module two is dependant on module one.

If I add dependency xyz to module one, module two will inherit it and doesn't need its own separate dependency xyz.

So I can code against xyz in module two if I either set up my IDE to use the poms in the project, or I build and install module one into my local repo.

But then when I commit the changes to git and the CI server runs the tests, it falls over because it picks up the old snapshot of module one from its local repo, which doesn't have the new dependency.

What is the correct approach to solving this on the CI server?

It seems I could force the CI test run to do local installs first, but that seems clunky.

Is there another way to instruct maven to use the latest poms and not the local repo when running aggregator jobs?

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a multi module build which contains both of your projects and handles that case well. Than you only need to build one project which contains two modules with the appropriate dependencies...

Comment: Do you mean I should put the xyz dependency into the parent pom?

Comment: [`mvn -U`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9697970/2646526)?