# Error to setup Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

First time I am setting up maven project on eclipse luna and I am getting below error on pom.xml file. i did to much google to resolve the issue but not able to resolve error.

Error:

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
 repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not 
 transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
 repo.maven.apache.org

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    vpp-plant-config-design
    vpp-plant-config-design
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    VPP Plant Config Design
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.4.0.RELEASE

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>ojdbc</groupId> <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId> <version>14</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
           <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>         
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>jfree</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
     <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
     <version>5.5.1</version>
   </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Try a forced update while you are connected to the internet. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update for more information.

Comment: Best is to delete the directory `$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache` and rebuild on command line first...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have the Maven default repository configuration that updates artifacts from the repositories once a day.

To solve this issue, you have 2 options:

1. Force maven to update using the `-U` option in the maven build command
2. Delete the directory of the dependency and run again the build command

Last but not least, you can change the `updatePolicy` of the repository. Give a look at the [Maven Repositories doc](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)