# issue in configuring spark-2.3.0 maven dependency for scala 2.11.12

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, pom.xml

I am getting issue while trying to setup maven denpendency in POM.xml for spark-scala application.

I am using :

SCALA Version

`$ scala`

`Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_162).`

SPARK VERSION:

`$ ./spark-shell`

`Welcome to SPARK version 2.3.0`

`Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_162)`

`Eclipse Version: 4.7.0`

in eclipse, I created a maven project with scala nature. I have selected "Latest 2.11 bundle(dynamic) in Scala Library container.

in POM.xml, I am trying to add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But I am getting below error in eclipse:

> > Failure to transfer com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
> >     org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
> >         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
> >         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
> >         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
> >         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
> >     .
> >     .
> >     .
> >     pom.xml /examples   line 1  Maven Dependency Problem

Comment: Can you try doing a force download of dependencies and project clean in eclipse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force maven update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update)