# Can't create spring boot starter project : Non - resolvable

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a spring boot starter project, but my parent packet has a problem, here is the error

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer 
>    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 
>    was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or 
>    updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:
>    2.0.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Unable to find acceptable protocols. 
>    isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
>    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_2, TLS_1_1, TLS_1_0], 
>    supportsTlsExtensions=true), ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
>    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
>    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_0], 
>    supportsTlsExtensions=true), ConnectionSpec()], supported protocols=[TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] and 
>    'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

here is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How did you run maven?

Comment: Try to remove <relativePath/> - I'm not sure why you have included it.

Comment: @morsor The given `<relativePath/>` is correct and should be there...

Comment: try running maven command "clean install -U" to force update the dependencies. If that does not work try removing all org.springframework dependencies from your local .m2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force maven update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update)

Comment: Why is relativePath correct or even needed? The error message states " 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM". The desired spring-boot-starter-parent should surely be found in a Maven repo and not merely in the parent directory?

Comment: i didn't run anything yet, just create a spring boot project and it happened from the beginning

Comment: The error message about the `relativePath` is a consequence of the previous errors and is not related to this network/connection/firewall/proxy issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with with following disciplines

> **Spring Boot** 2.0.3
>   **JDK** 1.8
>   **Packaging** WAR

and i noticed my AVG anti-virus was stopping eclipse to download the libraries.
After stopping AVG it is working.

Comment: i'm using AVG too, maybe this is the problem

Comment: yes try to disable and build again project maybe it would help you or manually go to AVG and disable some sort of AVG which is disabling the eclipsing to access internet

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue with linux distro 18.04 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1770553) while accessing ssl content; updating to 18.10 solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following command manually

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```