# Maven Build Not Finding Oracle

Tags: oracle, maven

I'm switching a maven project's db from MySQL to Oracle. I have this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But IntelliJ's maven view shows red squigglies on that dependency and *mvn clean install* gives me:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:polls:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

So per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update) advice, I did a force (mvn clean install -U). But that gives me:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.1.0/ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.1.0/ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar
```

... even though my .m2 does contain that dependency:

[image]

So why does my project not build? Is there some reason Oracle jars are not accessible via maven central?

Comment: Hi, could you print the content of the `pom.xml`? The artifact your giving does not exist (anymore?) on maven central, so it can only rely on the artifact in your local repository, maybe it is invalid?

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't noticed that version is not on maven central. Maybe my organization hosts a copy of it for our projects to access. But interestingly, even if I put a version of Oracle JDBC Driver that's supposedly current, I get same error: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4.0.

Comment: Oracle OJDBC Drivers are not in Central If you have found one which is there by accident. Only use your own internal repository manager...

Comment: @khmarbaise, out of curiosity, is there a specific reason they shouldn't be on maven central? (Though anyway I agree it is best to use your own repository manager).

Comment: Yes. The License of the OJDBC Drivers of Oracle do not allow that...

Comment: @khmarbaise, do you know if that's documented somewhere? It would explain what I’m seeing, but raises the question of why they’re listed in mvnrepository, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Oracle JDBC drivers need to be obtained from the "Oracle Maven Repository". There's [lots](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) of [guidance](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html) on that, which I guess I missed at first. They can also be downloaded [directly](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html).