# Why cannot resolve symbol TransactionWriteRequest or TransactionLoadRequest?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm studying the dynamodb, and running a sample code. I have imported all dependencies, but it says

> Cannot resolve symbol 'TransactionWriteRequest',
>   'TransactionLoadRequest','TransactionCanceledException' or
>   'DynamoDBTransactionWriteExpression'.

pom.xml:

```
xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.327</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

java:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.TransactionWriteRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.TransactionLoadRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.TransactionCanceledException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTransactionWriteExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTransactionLoadExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.InternalServerErrorException;
```

Comment: did you try clean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading the aws-java-sdk-dynamodb dependency version to 1.11.590.