# updates of karate-config.js are not seen in IntelliJ only after maven install

Tags: intellij-idea, karate

Install IntelliJ 2022 - 11.0.14.1 version / karate 1.1.0

Open project

Open karate-config.js and add a new parameter or change a value and save.

When running a test we get a failed message saying that the new parameter doesn't exist / or change is not seen.

As work-around deploy maven install to see all the updates or changes. Also works when running from command line 'mvn test ...'

Previous versions of IntelliJ worked ok.

Any help please.

Comment: not an issue with karate since it runs on the command-line. certainly sounds like you need to reload the maven project in intellij, read the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64803390/143475