# Trouble importing module for a Jenkins plugin

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm trying to modifie an existing plugin for Jenkins and i'm stuck when trying to add new import in Java.

this import in my .java file

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun;
```

I have try to add dependency in the pom.xml file.

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>structs</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-step-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-cps</artifactId>
        <version>2.56</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-scm-step</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-job</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-basic-steps</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-durable-task-step</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.30</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>scm-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci</groupId>
        <artifactId>symbol-annotation</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailer</artifactId>
        <version>1.20</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-aggregator</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-aggregator</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>script-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>scm-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and the error is **"package org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job does not exist"**

The command i use for build:

```
mvn verify
```

Can someone help me a bit?

thank you

Comment: Curious...are you trying to import this package in a Test class, or in a class under main/src/java ? The reason I ask is because your dependency has <scope>test</scope> which means it can only be used in Tests..

Comment: If in a Test class, do `mvn verify -U` to force upgrade of your dependencies

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/how-to-force-maven-update?rq=1

Comment: Ok i try to remove the <scope>test</scope> and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency for [`workflow-job`](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/workflow/workflow-job/2.9/).

Comment: It was already in the file. I have updated my question with the full dependecy

Comment: Maybe a file is corrupted. Try  to purge the local repo: `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

Comment: Thank for your answer.
Purge is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the test from the dependencies.
Thank you