# Problems using Hibernate 6 with Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am trying to use Hibernate 6 with Eclipse in a maven project. It's just a simple demo project (without spring or the like, just a simple java project with maven) to try to use Hiberate. However whatever I do I only run into errors. I have tried various versions of Hibernate and was only lucky with a very old version (4.x). However when I try to use Hibernate 5 or 6 I always get errors since Eclipe rsp. Maven can't download the needed files.

When I try to use Hibernate 6.1.3. Final, the corresponding dependency in my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

My code does not compile and I get the following error message

org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.1.3.Final failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.1.3.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

Of course there are much more errors because of the missing jar file, but that's not the issue here. My problem is that the relevant jar file for hibernate is not downloaded.

When I look into my local maven repository I see there are several files (e. g. the pom file and the a jar containing the sources and also the corresponding sha-files), but there is no jar file containing the classes.
There is also a file _remote.repositories containing the following lines:

```
#NOTE: This is a Maven Resolver internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Sep 26 13:07:00 CEST 2022
hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final-sources.jar>central=
hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.pom>central=
```

The same happens when I try to use the latest version of Hibernate 5 (5.6.11).

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to use Hibernate in a maven project (without spring or the like)=

Thanks for reading and helping,

Rudi

Comment: the article on https://dzone.com/articles/how-resolve-mavens-failure suggest to remove some files from the m2 repo caching the transfer failure

Comment: This could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/how-to-force-maven-update

Comment: Thanks very much. I deleted the file with the extension "lastUpdated" and updated the maven project forcing the update of snapshots/releases and now I finally could download the corresponding files.

Everything's fine now - thanks a lot, I was already knocking my head against the wall;-)