# Maven: Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am hoping someone can help me with a problem I am struggling with.

When I try to build my project from the terminal I get this error:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.morrislgn.merchandising.common:test-data-utils:jar:0.3b-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.morrislgn.merchandising:merchandising:pom:0.3b-SNAPSHOT
```

The `common.test-data-utils` jar is created by a separate project and shared between this and another project (the other project doesn't build either, but that is down to another problem).

I am able to build `com.morrislgn.merchandising.common:test-data-utils` without issue, I can see the entry it makes in the `.m2` local repository on my machine. I have reindexed my repository in Eclipse also.

The POM for my project has this entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.morrislgn.merchandising.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-data-utils</artifactId>
    <version>0.3b-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Which appears to be correct to me - the POM doesn't report any errors either when it is viewed in Eclipse.

Can some one tell me what I am missing here or doing wrong?

Comment: If someone (like me) encounters this error due to http repository in maven > 3.8.1, something like `maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories:`, refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67001968/6346531

Comment: @aksh1618 Thanks. That was the resolution for my issue

Comment: I just commented the default mirror section and all dependencies were downloaded then..

Answer (score 223):

You can always try `mvn -U clean install`

`-U` forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories.

Comment: @MrPhi: If you have the m2e plugin, then you can use Maven -> "Update Project...". The next dialog will have an option to force updates of snapshots and releases.

Comment: @AaronDigulla It's that dialog box which is causing the error for me.

Comment: To make this works you should run command being inside of root dir of your project

Comment: I had a similar issue as well. This really helps, and in addition, if you are using private mvn repo, make sure to add that to your `~/.m2/setting.xml` mirror section first, and then after running `mvn -U clean install`, make sure to `Reimport` (right click the project, then under the bottom `Maven` section there is a `Reimport` button).

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk : Yes there is. 
1. Windows-show view->Terminal.                                                                                   2. Add local terminal                                                                                                    3. cd PomFilePath                                                                                               4. Run the command

Answer (score 184):

This problem can occur if you have some child projects that refer to a parent pom and you have not installed from the parent pom directory (run `mvn install` from the parent directory). One of the child projects may depend on a sibling project and when it goes to read the pom of the sibling, it will fail with the error mentioned in the question unless you have installed from the parent pom directory at least once.

I just ran into this problem when moving a project to a new computer. I was in the habit of running commands from the child project and didn't run install on the parent.

Comment: In addition, when running `mvn install` on parent you can also add `-N` for non-recursive operation. This will cause maven to skip all the modules (including one that fails) and just do `install` goal for the parent.

Comment: @JacekPrucia good to know that a pom artifact also needs to be installed (if your parent is a pom)

Comment: @bzuillsmith why would you need to run `mvn install` in the parent pom. Wouldn't this only be used so the sibling dependency can be downloaded? If you happen to have went to the sibling directory & ran `mvn install` from there so that the jar is in your local repository, doesn't this accomplish the same exact thing?

Comment: It's been a few years since I've used maven, but--Yes, I believe you can install the sibling dependencies one by one. Installing from the parent just tends to be less work (fewer commands to type and run). There may be cases in large projects where you don't want all child projects installed in which case you would need to run them individually.

Comment: My project like ch-multip-spring\simple-parent\simple-model\pom.xml, I do mvn clean install from root ch-multip-spring folder(not from simple-parent as well), it solved my the issue similar to the post title.

Comment: @bzuillsmith Wow! This answer did save me. Doing `mvn install` at least once on the parent pom is the key! My spring-boot subproject kept failing to resolve the dependency on a sibling subproject, even if I did `mvn install` **on that sibling**! But once I did `mvn -N install` on the parent, the spring-boot subproject finally started to work. So, again, `mvn -N install` on the parent is the key. (although I don't know why yet)

Comment: Man, you a life saver! Been wasting days trying to figure out why it failed on my project...

Answer (score 144):

Had the same issue with IntelliJ IDEA and following worked.

- Go to `File`
- Select `Settings`
- Select `Build, Execution, Deployments`
- Select `Build Tools` from drop down
- Select `Maven` from drop down
- Tick the `Always update snapshots` check box

[image: screen shot of IntelliJ 2017.2 > Preferences/Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Always update snapshots (checkbox)]

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't understand why - I was attempting to build from the command line. Was there something cached from IntelliJ?

Comment: Worked for me too! Can't believe how frustrating this was. Thanks!

Comment: @ goodOldFashioned: This "always update" overwrote the ....lastUpdated file from the local repository.   -U does the same from the commandline.  So intellij fixed your local repo, and then the commandline worked again.

Comment: Simple and effective

Comment: after browsing the whole internet, finally this worked for me

Answer (score 58):

If you are using Eclipse, **Right Click on your Project** -> **Maven** -> **Update Project**. It will open Update Maven Project dialog box.

In that dialog box, check **Force Update of Snapshots/Releases** checkbox & click **OK**. (Please refer image below)

[image: Update Maven Project Dialog Box]

This worked for me !

Answer (score 40):

If you're using Eclipse:

- *Right click on project > Properties > Maven*
- Make sure that *Resolve dependencies from workspace projects* is not clicked.

Comment: It works for me. But I dont understand why? Any explanation behind this?

Comment: this did not work for me, initially 12 decencies were missing, after doing this it is 74 now

Answer (score 29):

I know I'm pretty late to the conversation, but I had this problem too. I think the issue was my company's firewall. My solution was to unplug from the network, connect to our open wireless and then force an update via Eclipse. This resolved everything.

Comment: You need to have put in [proxy info into your .m2/settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue with eclipse where the maven build command line worked just fine BUT 
try this

- go into .m2/repository and wipe the directory associated
- run update maven dependencies in eclipse

The error goes away....why my mvn command line worked with those directories and eclipse .m2eclipse could not, I have no idea and it kinda sucks.  My project is now working in eclipse again.

Comment: on a side note, we switched to gradle....so much happier than ant and maven....extremely nice setup.

Comment: Not even sure it's anything Eclipse-related. I had the same issue with IntelliJ and deleting the problematic packages and re-running `mvn clean install` worked

Answer (score 14):

I had same problem using IntelliJ. I solved with right click on pom.xml > Maven > Reimport

Comment: Yeah, like life is just that simple. Anyways, @prime answer worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this issue by deleting in the repository folders where this error was shown everything except the .jar and .pom files.

Comment: I have also solved the same issue by deleting related files in the maven local repository and then update the whole project.

Answer (score 9):

For me , it was related to setting the "User Setting.xml" inside

```
Window > preferences > Maven > User Settings > and then browsing to the user Settings inside the { maven unarchived directory / }/apache-maven-2.2.1/conf/settings.xml .
```

Answer (score 8):

"Failed to read artifact descriptor" problems generally indicate a problem with the dependency's pom file in the maven repository. I would suggest you to double check if the pom file's name is the same with the name maven expects, and also to check if the pom file contents are valid.

Comment: The check of the pom.xml was useful. I found I had same dependency twice (copy & paste error). After cleanup everything was fine.

Answer (score 8):

Navigate via shell inside of your project folder and run following command:

```sh
mvn -U clean install
```

Usually this should already solve your problem.

If you see a message like this:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project :war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9

Then execute:

```sh
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

followed by:

```sh
mvn -U clean install
```

again to finally update your dependencies.

Afterwards perform clean maven build:

```sh
maven clean install
```

Answer (score 7):

I have a project

```
 A/
 |--a1
 |--a2
```

Now there is another project in our org

```
 B/
 |--b1
 |--b2
 |--b3
```

(Every module a1, b1 etc. and Parent projects A, B have their own pom.xml as per standard maven rules of parent and child)

Both projects are checked out on my local eclipse (from SVN). I am actively working on A.

I came to know that there is a good common functionality (b4) developed in B and I needed to use it.

```
 B/
 |--b1
 |--b2
 |--b3
 |--b4 (NEW)
```

Developer of b4 have deployed this b4 module as an artifact in our org's repository. I included the dependancy to my module's POM i.e. a2's pom.xml. Eclipse downloaded the reuqired artifact from repo and I could import the classes in it.

Now issue starts...
I needed to check the source code of b4 for some purpose and as I already had B checked out on my local eclipse I updated it from SVN and checked out module b4. I also ran pom.xml of module b4 with targets like clean, package etc.
After some time when I finishedd my coding I needed to create a JAR of my module a2. I ran "package" on a2's pom.xml and BAM!! errors n errors for a2 module.. These errors were also not very user friendly. Only thing is there was b4's name for sure in logs.

Solution:
After trying for many solutions for many hours, I ran "mvn -U clean install" from console in my B's  project directoty (i.e. in ../codebase/B). As B is the parent, clean install command ran for all modules including b4 and it ran successfully. After this I ran "mvn -U clean install" for my parent project which is A. And this worked! a2 module got compiled, installed, (packaged later) succesfully.

Here important point was if b4 is in your workspace do not only install b4. You will need to clean-install complete B. I came up to this solution after reading answer from **Zuill**

**EDIT: One more thing here to note that if I didn't had B project checked out in Local environment then this issue might not have occurred for me. I tend to think that this happened cause I had B checked out in my local workspace.**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I meet the same problem, project A add a dependency from project B's submodule B-IDL. I should mvn deploy whole B project, not just mvn deploy submodule B-IDL.

Answer (score 5):

You mention two different groupIds, `com.morrislgn.merchandising.common` and `com.johnlewis.jec.webpim.common`. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Good spot - no, its not unfortunatly. I copied the wrong tag from the POM XML, that was the one above the tag I needed and didnt spot what I'd done. Ooops! I've edited the question to fix my stupidity!

Answer (score 5):

For me, it seems to actually have been a problem with the dependency POM.

I worked around it by using the jitpack virtual repository, with which you can include github repositories based on their URL instead of their own POM (which seems to have been erroneous in my case).

```
<repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: This worked for me. The repository section of the pom.xml file should be properly updated and the </id> tag should be the name of the repository. Saved a lot of my time!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem for a while and despite doing `mvn -U clean install` the problem was not getting solved!

I finally solved the problem by deleting the whole `.m2` folder and then restarted my IDE and the problem was gone!

So sometimes the problem would rise because of some incompatibilities or problems in your local maven repository.

Comment: Tried doing a Maven resync while offline, and completely hosed IntelliJ. Followed your advice, deleted .m2, and now it's working like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Reference 
[Maven error "Failure to transfer..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer)

```
find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

In our case the error appeared because of the incorrect groupId renaming while some of the projects in multi-module Maven configuration references to others.

We had an aggregator project (`billing-parent`) with two modules (`billing-api`, `billing`):

```
com.company.team:billing-parent
|-com.company.team:billing-api
|-com.company.team:billing
```

Project `billing` depends on `billing-api`. So in its `pom.xml` it had:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.team</groupId>
    <artifactId>billing-api</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

We decided to rename groupId from `com.company.team` to `com.company.team.billing`. We replaced old value in parent's `pom.xml` and in `<parent>` sections of both modules. But forgot to update dependency above. So we had got configuration in which `billing` project references old `billing-api` artifact. Eventually it beaks build of the `billing` module after some time with the error like

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project billing: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.team.billing:billing:jar:3.5.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.company.team:billing-api:jar:3.5.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.company.team:billing-api:jar:3.5.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find <parent of the com.company.team:billing-parent project which is not available any more>`

despite the fact that `billing-api` module builds without errors.

Solution 1: rename `groupId` in `dependency` as well.

Solution 2: replace `groupId` by the `${project.groupId}` property like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>billing-api</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Conclusion.**
So my advice in case you encountered with the error in multi-module configuration whould be: thoroughly check `groupId` and `artifactId` of the dependencies on neighbour modules.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm brave, nine years after the question...

For me it was a problem where sub-dependencies weren't found. I finally found the real issue by looking at the "Error Log"-view that held a `An internal error occurred during: "Building".`-line. Double-clicking it showed a pop-up with a stacktrace and the last cause finally disclosed a broken JAR in my local repository. I cleaned that up and Eclipse/m2e was able to work again.

Comment: thanks! this looks a better lead to investigate in my case !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  In my case, the version of testng in my .m2/repositories folder was corrupt, but when I deleted it & did a maven update again, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This error is basically saying that maven couldn't read a certain dependency from local repository. It might happend because a jar file didn't get downloaded correctly. So, go to your maven local repository and make sure there isn't any **.lastUpdated** extension file.

Comment: This was my issue. Once I deleted the lastUpdated file for the dependency which was failing it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

From the IDE (*Red Hat CodeReady Studio* in my case, but [@mavaddat-javid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1757756/mavaddat-javid) has verified in VS Code 1.77.0).

Windows -> Show View -> Terminal -> Open/Add local terminal

Run commands as follows >

$ `cd /pom-file-path/`

$ `mvn -U clean install`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in eclipse, `mvn -U clean install` didn't work but right clicking the project and selecting Maven->Update Project fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using STS Eclipse with first time using Maven. The project I setup already had its own settings.xml. If this is the case, you'll want to update your settings.xml file in run configuration.

1. right click the pom.xml and "Run As" -> "Run Configurations..."
2. where it says "User settings" click on the File button and add the settings.xml.
3. I think this is specific to your project but my "Goals" is set to "clean install" and I checked on "Skip Tests."

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this question because it is the first one goggle finds. In my case, root cause was hidden in the stack trace of the problem:

```
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:pom:1.2.2 failed to transfer from https://nexus.akbankpreprod.com/repository/maven-public/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of maven-public has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:pom:1.2.2 from/to maven-public (https://nexus.akbankpreprod.com/repository/maven-public/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

"Original error" section says I need to add my nexus server's sercurity certificate to jre trust store.