# Couldn't use maven dependecies

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10: 
ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.aspectj:aspectjrt:pom:1.6.10 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.aspectj:aspectjrt:pom:1.6.10 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
```

**Or this:**
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library `C:\Users\...\\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar` p1      Build path  Build Path Problem

**And this:**
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    p1      Unknown Java Problem

How to solve this maven problem?

Comment: Have u seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor

Comment: Why does it say "the operation was cancelled"?

Comment: I think that this is because I install mvn plugin, but I haven't already installed mvn on my computer. I'll check in evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by adding 

    
      central
      Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com
      http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2
      central