# maven fail to download artifact while it does exist

Tags: maven

i have project which needs to download an artifact from our internal nexus server, the artifact is jar file defined in the

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.tibco.datasynapse.qa.testharness-commons.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>java${jdk.version}</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.18</version>
  <classifier>commons</classifier>
</dependency>
```

and the error is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project java1.7: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tibco.datasynapse.qa.grid-testharness.java:java1.7:jar:6.2.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 

Failed to collect dependencies for [com.tibco.datasynapse.qa.testharness-commons.java:java1.7:jar:commons:1.0.0.18 (compile), com.tibco.datasynapse.grid.sdk:java:jar:6.2.0.139604 (compile), com.tibco.datasynapse.grid.speedlink:java:jar:6.2.0.139604 (compile), com.tibco.datasynapse.qa:grid-soap:jar:6.2.0.3 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 (compile), javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.10 (compile), oro:oro:jar:2.0.8 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.tibco.datasynapse.qa.testharness-commons.java:java1.7:jar:commons:1.0.0.18: Could not find artifact com.tibco.datasynapse.qa.testharness-commons.java:java:pom:1.0.0.18 in qa-releases (http://athena.grid.datasynapse.com/nexus/content/repositories/qa-releases) -> [Help 1]
```

but the truth is this artifact does exist in the right place, it doesn't work even if i copied the dependency info from nexus gui of this artifact

i tried -U arg, tried upload an artifact with new version, tried deleting the folder where the target artifact should be downloaded to, none of these works...

i found a thread, [Maven: Failed to read artifact descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor), but doesn't work to me either...

the artifact looks like this on nexus
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeg7y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Even when you install it manually ? try it if it's not already done