# Error on running my app

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I'm new to eclipse and wanted to make a web app. after converting dynamic project into Maven project I'm getting this error. Can anyone help?

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Testing'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6642146/6505250

Comment: Can you, please, provide maven build file?