# Maven dependencies jars not getting updated or error in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am beginner in Maven development, Need our help to fix this issue. I can see jars are not available at `.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.1.0.RELEASE`

only below jars are avaialble

```
spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar.lastUpdated  
spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.pom.lastUpdated
```

[image]

Also I am getting below error in `pom.xml`

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'cim'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

[image]

Comment: go to the project menu, then down to maven and update the project, also Alt-F5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: Failed to read artifact descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor)

Comment: Can you able to build the application in cmd prompt/terminal?

Comment: Have tried to update the project and didn't help ..

Comment: coreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are in need of the SpringBoot starters. In your project parent module you can use

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

There are many specialized bundles like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And many more like spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-batch, spring-boot-starter-data-rest...
See [this blog article for more](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters).

Comment: This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

remove all missing jars from library and add this dependency in pom.xml
into dependencies tag

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

after this right click on project click on maven and click on update project or just press ( alt+F5 )

Comment: Upgrading spring may break the application. the issue downloading maven dependency not spring itself.

Comment: Any other thoughts ? @KarthikeyanVaithilingam

Comment: @Sreekumar with out seeing the maven error cannot point the issue. try building in cmd/terminal and post the error.

Comment: coreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

Answer (score 0):

Add springboot starters to the POM.xml