# Selenium - Maven Dependency -Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I'm new to Maven, and programming in general. All i have done is created this project and added selenium and testng dependencies in the pom.xml file.

When i did the maven import, for some reason pom is throwing an error saying that it cannot read artifact descriptor for selenium jar. I have used the same dependencies in other projects and they seem to import just fine.

You can see the pom below in the screenshot. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but i honestly don't know what's wrong here, and i can't seem to find a solution with google searches.

Btw, when i run mvn install, i get a "BUILD SUCCESS"..so not sure what the deal is. Help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here tick the option Setting>Maven>always update the snapshot. Maybe some files are cached on your system.
for detail check this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45697349/8604768

Comment: Hi Waqar, thanks for the answer! hmm this does seem to work, although i don't really understand why. I created yet another project just now, and even though i left the "Always update snapshots" option unchecked, i still didn't get any problems importing the dependencies! I guess this is one of those weird things that just happens sometime. But i appreciate your response!