# Access denied to central maven repository

Tags: maven

I have a server which is behind a security proxy. The security proxy is opened for `https://repo.maven.apache.org.` However, when I try to download a plugin. E.g. `soapui-maven-plugin:5.5.0` I receive an access denied error message. It doesn't matter which plugin I try to download.

Some System information:

- SLES12
- Maven:`mvn -v
  Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T17:06:16+02:00)
  Maven home: /usr/local/lib/maven/apache-maven-3.6.2
  Java version: 1.8.0_231, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_231-amd64/jre
  Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
  OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.178-94.91-default", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`
- Root user -> No other user involved

The whole error message:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:jar:5.5.0
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:jar:5.5.0
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:pom:5.5.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/5.5.0/soapui-maven-plugin-5.5.0.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:pom:5.5.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/5.5.0/soapui-maven-plugin-5.5.0.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/5.5.0/soapui-maven-plugin-5.5.0.pom
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1141)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1094)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor) if it is of some help

Comment: Thanks for your link. Unfortunately, I already tried that solution without success

Comment: i see the dependency you are trying is being fetched from "https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html" which is not permitted by your server proxy and also there is a [smartbear community](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/SOAP-UI-and-Maven-integration-Failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor/td-p/125639) link that you can see some changes in settings.xml

Comment: Ok, maybe it has been a bad example from my side with the soapui plugin.
However, as I wrote above, it doesn't matter which plugin I try to use. A more general example would be:

Comment: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom ->

Comment: did you open the pom.xml of plugin and see the connection url???

Comment: Sorry, I am not maven pro. I just had a look into the pom and found
<connection>
scm:svn:http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/tags/maven-clean-plugin-2.5
</connection>
Does it mean, that when I want to use that pom file, my proxy needs to allow svn.apache.org?

Comment: give it a shot, cause that is what we do try debug and analyse

Comment: Thank you so much so far. Unfortunately, I don't have access to that proxy, so I have to raise a ticket. I post an update as soon as I was able to test it.