# Intellij-idea cannot resolve spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I created a spring boot maven project. Everything was fine until I added spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb to the dependencies like below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Intellij-idea complains

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.3.2.RELEASE

and

> Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.3.2.RELEASE' not found

Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Does this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor solves your problem?

Comment: Try this: https://start.spring.io/ -> Select the Dependency (NoSQL Spring Data MongoDB) -> Generate the project. The generated ZIP file can be imported (Open or Import) into your IDE. Build and run.

Comment: Check the pom.xml from the generated project ZIP file for the correct dependencies.

Comment: have you tried `mvn clean install` in terminal

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. This seems something to do with the built-in Maven in the Intellij-idea. After I downloaded and installed the latest Maven 3.6.3 and set the path in the System Path, the project starts to recognise the mongodb.

Comment: You also have other option in intellij, `invalidate caches and restart`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Reloading Project solved the issue for me.