# Dependency 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200' not found, Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.h2database:h2:jar

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am building backend application support using Springboot and trying to use h2 database in-built with Spring. However, when I add the below h2 dependency in pom.xml, it's erroring out.

## Error

## Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200
Dependency 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200' not found

## pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.3.RELEASE
 

com.krishnaQuiz
Krishna-Quiz
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Krishna-Quiz
Krishna Quiz UI

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

============================

Please help

Comment: Have you configured the h2 database in `application.properties` file like `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`, etc?

Comment: Yes, below is the content of application.properties
=============================
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: try removing the `<scope>runtime</scope>` and check it

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Hi, can you try this ? [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642146/maven-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor)!

Comment: `maven clean`,`maven install`, `maven build` try this command.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem ... Specify the H2 version in your pom.xml and wait to update.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

An error will appear in the test file, just open it and update the import "CTRL+SHIFT+O" if you use eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error upon adding any new dependency to my pom.xml file. However, reloading the maven dependencies worked for me [refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vREKj.png).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem in my case I resolved it by- in intellij go to maven and simply reload the maven projects it will work or you can use mvn clean install command