# How to overwrite version of spring boot BOM

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter-parent

I have a problem with updating Log4j versions. In my `pom.xml` file I updated the version like this:

```
<properties>
        // other stuff //
        <org.apache.logging.log4j.version>2.16.0</org.apache.logging.log4j.version>
    </properties>
```

But in the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>{org.apache.logging.log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>{org.apache.logging.log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

The versions throw an error that it's override to 2.11.1 from a BOM file. Where can I update my `pom` to import a 2.16.0 version BOM file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So both answers helped me out finding the solution for my problem. The problem was that in my `dependency` I didn't put a `$` sign for my `version` tag. So with this line of code it works now: `<version>${org.apache.logging.log4j.version}</version>`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try this to override spring-boot bom.

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        ... other dependencies including spring-boot-dependencies
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### NOT GOOD/no effect(maybe for log4j1):

```
<org.apache.logging.log4j.version>2.16.0</org.apache.logging.log4j.version>
```

### Better

#### (for spring-boot-parent-based [2-2.6.1]/spring-dependeny-managed):

```
<log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
```

;)

[Link](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot)

Comment: I have some other errors after changing the tags. I got this in my plugins section of pom: ```'build.pluginManagement.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin```

Comment: this (latest) is an "easy fix"! (just read the error message: "found duplicate declaration of plugin ..surefire..")

Comment: sry copied in wrong one, I managed that one, I have trouble with this one: ```Plugin could not be resolved. Ensure the plugin's groupId, artifactId and version are present. Additional information: Plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to 
 read artifact descriptor for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.3```

Comment: uff, this is harder (& probably not related) [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6642146/592355) ..it could be (temporal/permanent) network issue, or something with your "company (maven) repository"...if all fails: just download it (to local maven repo (`~/.m2/repository`))