# Spring and Maven plugin installation issue; mvn; spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, maven-plugin

i've a maven based project and i'm trying to import it to Spring source tool suite. I am getting the following error.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not calculate build plan: Missing:
----------
1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:maven-plugin:2.4.2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-resources-plugin -Dversion=2.4.2 -Dpackaging=maven-plugin -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-resources-plugin -Dversion=2.4.2 -Dpackaging=maven-plugin -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:maven-plugin:2.4.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
    Gamex       Unknown Maven Problem
```

It looks like it's asking me to install the maven resourource plugin 2.4.2 but I'm not sure what is the file to download. I tried downloading maven-plugin-plugin-2.4.2-source.jar and feeding it to the command; but it didn't work.
I then went to the maven repository in http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-resources-plugin-2.4.2/ and downloaded the pof.xml; this also is not working.
If you have seen this problem before pls help me understand what is missing / or what the error message is.

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-problem-failure-to-transfer is causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the maven resourource plugin 2.4.2[maven-resources-plugin-2.4.2.jar] from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.4.2/  and do an

```
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-resources-plugin -Dversion=2.4.2 -Dpackaging=maven-plugin -Dfile=/path/to/file
```

followed by clean eclipse :eclipse , clean the project in Eclipse and refresh and try . It should work .

Answer (score 1):

You may be behind firewall. You could try to set an `HTTP` proxy to bypass the firewall.

In Windows, this file is located at: `C:\Documents and Settings\<windows Login>\.m2\settings.xml`

You need to provide valid parameters to the `<proxy>` based on how the network is setup in your organization.

```
<settings 
...
     <proxies>

    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>put-ur-proxy-servername</host>
      <port>80</port>
    </proxy>
...
</settings>
```