# Spring Security 3.0.3.RELEASE: ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer

Tags: spring, spring-security, maven-3, pom.xml

Following is the error I for spring security 3 at the time of resolving dependencies:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Missing artifact org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE
    - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer 
     org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE from http://
     repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
     reattempted until the update interval of com.springsource.repository.bundles.release has elapsed or updates are 
     forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:jar:
     3.0.3.RELEASE from/to com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/
     bundles/release): connection timed out to http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/
     springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/
     org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Following is how spring security 3 dependencies defined in my pom file:

```
        <!-- Spring Security dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.security.acls</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.security.config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.security.core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.security.taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.security.web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Following are the repositories I have defined in the pom:

```
    <!-- SpringSource EBR repos -->
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else having this problem and ending up here, [try this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested the url:

`http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar`

and it worked without problem (I get the file).

Remove (or rename for backup) the folder `org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE` from your local m2 repository and try it again.