# Maven build failure: Read time out

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

I have tried all the possible solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer), including:

1. find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
2. mvn -U clean

It does not work anyway, the specific log is as below:

btw: I was trying to run a struts2 sample code from [mkyong site](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hello-world-annotation-example/)

---

```
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] com.mkyong.common:Struts2Example:war:com.mkyong.common
[DEBUG]    junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[DEBUG]    org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8:compile
[DEBUG]       com.opensymphony:xwork-core:jar:2.1.6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.6:compile
[DEBUG]             commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.15:compile
[DEBUG]       ognl:ognl:jar:2.7.3:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0:system
[DEBUG]    org.apache.struts:struts2-convention-plugin:jar:2.1.8:compile
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo
.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/
2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file D:\ProgramData\apache-maven-repo\.m2\re
pository\org\apache\struts\struts2-core\2.1.8\struts2-core-2.1.8.jar.lastUpdated

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 52:31.162s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 18 20:16:49 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/5M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Struts2Example: Could not resolve depe
ndencies for project com.mkyong.common:Struts2Example:war:com.mkyong.common: Cou
ld not transfer artifact org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8 from/to centra
l (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/struts/strut
s2-core/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar from central failed: Read timed out -> [Hel
p 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project Struts2Example: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mkyong.
common:Struts2Example:war:com.mkyong.common: Could not transfer artifact org.apa
che.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/
maven2): GET request of: org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8
.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not res
olve dependencies for project com.mkyong.common:Struts2Example:war:com.mkyong.co
mmon: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8 from/
to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/str
uts/struts2-core/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could n
ot transfer artifact org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8 from/to central (h
ttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/struts/struts2-c
ore/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar from central failed
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
 transfer artifact org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8 from/to central (htt
p://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/struts/struts2-cor
e/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar from central failed
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Def
aultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArti
facts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not tra
nsfer artifact org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8 from/to central (http://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.
1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar from central failed
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(W
agonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(W
agonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.
run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(Run
nableErrorForwarder.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: GET request of: org/a
pache/struts/struts2-core/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:3
49)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:3
10)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:2
87)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.
run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSess
ionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:187)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.ContentLengt
hInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.EofSensorInputS
tream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:493)

        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.getTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:3
39)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Read timed out` means you have a network problem. Either `repo.maven.apache.org` is down (very unlikely) or you have connectivity issues on your end.

Comment: I guess so too, but I managed to use chrome to download the jar file~ the average download speed is below 10kps though...I wonder which files should I manually download for maven using directly?

Answer (score 1):

Read Timeout errors can also happen with big dependency resolution on slow networks (that you may not be able to fix by yourself). You may also want to consider this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837790/how-can-i-adjust-timeout-for-mvn-mirror-on-dependencyresolve-error-transferr), here you will find how to increase the Maven Wagon timeout which will help you in such cases.

Also check the [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

But using wget I am able to download instance. It is almost halt here..waited more than 15 mins..

INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.13:check (validate-checkstyle) @ onos ---
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.2/doxia-module-xhtml-1.2.pom
2/2 KB

Regards,
Bala

Comment: i did manully update my local repository using wget and re-run the mvn solved the problem.