# How can I adjust timeout for mvn mirror on dependency:resolve -- Error transferring file: Read timed out

Tags: maven, timeout, nexus, sonatype, maven-wagon-plugin

Does anyone know how to control the timeout settings for a **mirror** in the maven settings file or in the dependency plugin?

I see that I can modify timeout settings for a server but not a repository or a mirror.

**Problem**

Since upgrading nexus oss from 1.8.0 to 2.3x and moving to a VM I'm seeing **intermittent** problems with timeouts and nothing useful in the nexus debug log alas.   I figure I have two options: improve nexus server performance or configure maven settings to wait longer for artifacts.

I don't see much to do with my server so I'm looking into the maven side.

**Maven Error on Dependency Resolve**

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project foo: 

from/to snapshots (http://mycorp.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Error transferring file: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
```

Please let me know if you know to configure maven's wagon etc. to relax its timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a simple http get to see what performance you get outside of Maven first. Might be a proxy issue or so.

Wagon is the name of the component doing HTTP transport in Maven and you can find some more info and config tips at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html

Comment: It is an intermittent problem.  So, that would work and maven dependency would work later on as well.  It makes it somewhat difficult to test/fix

Comment: If it intermittent you need to figure out what goes wrong at the time. Probably a network or load problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of anyway to adjust the timeout?  I tried but there's no evidence of the change taking effect in the effective-pom or when running mvn using -X

Comment: Updated the answer .. maybe that helps

Comment: Excellent, that does help.  I've been looking at settings reference which was the wrong direction.  I haven't done much with the wagon so I guess this is my chance to dive deep.   Thanks

Comment: Looking at that link, it says that "With Wagon 2.0 and Apache Maven 3.0.4, a default timeout of 30 minutes comes by default." Was your file really not downloaded after 30 minutes? I'm getting a Read Time Out error after only a few minutes.