# Cannot download Maven Resources Plugin when building in Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, plugins, jenkins

I have created Selenium IDE test cases and have tested them in Eclipse. The project is a Maven java project and the tests will run fine in Eclipse however, when I add the project to Jenkins and try to build my project, there is a error and a build failure.

The error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Selenium IDE Recon
Parsing POMs
Discovered a new module Test:SeleniumTest SeleniumTest
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
[Selenium IDE Recon] $ C:\java/bin/java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-agent-1.5.jar;C:\Users\MC44948\Software\springsource\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar" org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main C:\Users\MC44948\Software\springsource\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.4 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.45.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-1.5.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar" 53032
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\MC44948\Spring_Workspace\Selenium IDE Recon\pom.xml install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.671s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 29 11:46:35 BST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/8M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\MC44948\Spring_Workspace\Selenium IDE Recon\pom.xml to Test/SeleniumTest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SeleniumTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

My pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SeleniumTest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.43.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.43.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                <version>0.16</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to Internet connectivity. Did you notice the error: `"Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org"`?

Try `wget http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom` and see if you can fetch data.

For more details, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323678/error-in-resolving-buildtime-dependencies-while-installing-cloudstack-on-ubuntu) link.

Answer (score 1):

### You can try also this...

My Java project was building successfully when building from command line, but I was getting an error **"Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org"** when building it with Jenkins.

The problem was is the custom maven settings file which our company was using.

So what you can do is: Under Job configuration, Build section, click **"Advanced..."**.
Set the **"Settings file"** to **"Settings file in filesystem"** and give the path to the setting file from your maven installation location. For example
 **C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.1.1\conf\settings.xml**

Set the **"Global Settings file"** to **"Global settings file on filesystem"** and give the path to the **"${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml"**.

Answer (score 0):

You might be behind cooperate proxy (or any other proxy\firewall).
Make sure you can access maven central from the slave you're running your build.

If not - configure your http_proxy and https_proxy on your server.