# Netbeans 8.2 Maven java fx error in building project

Tags: maven

I worked on netbeans 8.2 so there when i create a project on maven -javafx the project does not buiilt it gives the following error.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-
plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: 
Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate failed:
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1 
or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3, 
org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1: 
Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3 from/to central 
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
```

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

A picture is also attached please help me solve this problem.[picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQHOQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you cannot reach the maven repository to download the dependencies!

see [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323678/error-in-resolving-buildtime-dependencies-while-installing-cloudstack-on-ubuntu) it helps find out which is the problem.

The url http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 you are using is it correct?
Can you reach this address from the machine on which you run the maven build?