# How can I set alternative build target to Intellij IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

How can I set alternative build target folder to Intellij IDEA?

I need that IDEA always builds all modules of my project into separate build output folders, say `target-idea` instead of `target`.

The reason is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887602/maven-resources-plugin2-5-cannot-create-resource-output-directory).

Weird as it migth be, [this option](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-compiler-output.html) simply does **NOT** work with my IDEA 13 edition(it does nothing)...

"Inherit project compile output folder" does something weird as well.

Comment: Hi, in your project structure (F4 on the project module), you can check two places : Project, "Project compiler output" which may point to an alternative folder. Artifacts, you have "Output directory" where you can set where you want to create the artifacts

Comment: I saw this, but I cannot make it work for all modules. Should I configure them manually one by one?

Comment: Maybe in modules of this window, select "Inherit project compile output path" from Path tab. I have to admit I haven't had the need yet

Comment: Weird as it might get, neither the "Inherit project compile output path" works, **neither** the option itself!!!

Comment: The hassle of occasionally receiving an error message, and the inconvenience of having to run maven again, pale into insignificance compared to running maven with a different configuration to intellij, and running either in a non-standard way.

Comment: You are probably right, since it looks like no one is doing it.
But I think the target(output folder) would be nice to be configurable, it is a destination after all.