# Maven-resources-plugin error

Tags: java, maven

I ran mvn clean install command on my project and I was getting the below error. This is a java web project . Can you please let me know what is the cause of this problem. Thanks in advance

[image]

Below is my pom.xml

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>eidmsidf.un.org.Contactus</groupId>
      <artifactId>Contactus</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
                <version>${jackson.version}</version> </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                <version>0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                <artifactId>displaytag-export-poi</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                <artifactId>displaytag-portlet</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.22</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ognl</groupId>
                <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.oracle</groupId> <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId> 
                <version>11.2.0.3</version> </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>nl.captcha</groupId> <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId> 
                <version>1.2.1</version> </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.30</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
                <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.30</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.3.01</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/javax.mail-1.3.3.01.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency> 
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error output, your picture gets cut off.

Comment: Why don't you follow the Maven default directory layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, there reasons for being unable to create a folder are:

Some other process is deleting this folder at the same time
You don't have permissions to access this folder
The folder is on a network share
Network shares are notoriously unreliable on Windows. Don't use them for any automated tasks. Always build projects with all files residing on a local hard disk.

If you use Maven and Eclipse to build at the same time, you should configure them to use different target folders. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54366009/34088

Your POM should look like this:

```
<project>
 ...

<build>
<outputDirectory>${basedir}/${target.dir}/classes</outputDirectory>
<testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/${target.dir}/test-
classes</testOutputDirectory>
</build>

<properties>
<target.dir>target</target.dir>
</properties>

<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>eclipse-folders</id>
  <properties>
    <target.dir>target-eclipse</target.dir>
  </properties>
 </profile>
  </profiles>
```

...

All that's left is to enable the profile eclipse-folders in the IDE.

Comment: You should also mention it is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887602/maven-resources-plugin2-5-cannot-create-resource-output-directory). C drive in windows can never be a network drive!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the exception, maven can't create directory. Try to create this directory manually to ensure that path is valid and you have enough rights.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

1. Some other process might be deleting the folder at the same time you run `mvn`
2. You don't have enough privileges to write data to `C:\GIT_REPOSITORIES\` directory.

If you have admin access, you can run `mvn clean install` as an admin from cmd prompt. Else, get enough permissions to write data to the above mentioned directory.

Hope this helps!