# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources

Tags: apache, maven, build-error, apache-apex

I am executing the mvn clean install -DskipTests -X command in apex-core folder lying under my work directory to run an apache apex application. But there is a build error which says :

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources
>   (default-resources) on project apex-app-archetype: Cannot create
>   resource output directory: /home/abhinay/work/apex-core/target/classes
>   .

The work folder is in my home so I dont think its an issue of permission. 
I have also tried adding a resource outputDirectory in the pom.xml stating the target/classes but it does not allow  tag.

Comment: Your post looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887602/maven-resources-plugin2-5-cannot-create-resource-output-directory), did you find anything useful there?

Comment: show the log output of -X ...