# Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin

Tags: spring

I am facing this issue when i try to import the project on spring 3.6, can anyone help me to solve this problem thanks in advance.

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

Comment: is there an active proxy server in place? if so, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334394/could-not-transfer-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-pluginpom2

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately the project doesn't uses any proxy server

Comment: but does your local network use a proxy that you don't know about ? i.e. my workplace uses a proxy