# Exporting data to excel file using spring mvc

Tags: java, excel, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am begginer java developer and I use spring mvc framework I want to export data from jsp page (that was sent from controler) I work according to this tutorial 
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-excel-view-example-apache-poi-and-jexcelapi

but i get this error:

`HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is`     `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean` `with name 'excelView': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is` `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font`

when i want to use the "excel lib" poi-3.9.jar and put it as dependency in pom.xml

When i do "maven install" i got this error:

`Failed to execute goal on project SpringMvcJdbcTemplate: Could not resolve` `dependencies for project net.codejava.spring:SpringMvcJdbcTemplate:war:1.0:` `Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9: Failed to read` `artifact descriptor for org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9: Could not transfer artifact`

```
org.apache.poi:poi:pom:3.9 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

so i add the library in regular way and its seems good but when i run the app i got the error i put in the begining

This is my code:

controler:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView downloadExcel() {
    // create some sample data
   // return a view which will be resolved by an excel view resolver
    return new ModelAndView("excelView", "listContactings", listContact);
}
```

MvcConfigiration:

```
@Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        ResourceBundleViewResolver resolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setBasename("views");
        return resolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver2(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setOrder(2);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```

views.proprties:

```
excelView.(class)=net.codejava.spring.ExcelBuilder
```

ExcelBuilder.java:

```
package net.codejava.spring;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractExcelView;

import net.codejava.spring.model.Contacting;

public class ExcelBuilder extends AbstractExcelView {

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
            HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        // get data model which is passed by the Spring container
        List<Contacting> listContactings = (List<Contacting>) model.get("listContactings");

        // create a new Excel sheet
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");
        sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(30);

        // create style for header cells
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
       font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        style.setFont(font);

        // create header row

        HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);

        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("contacting_id");
        header.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("user_id");
        header.getCell(1).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(2).setCellValue("subject");
        header.getCell(2).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(3).setCellValue("location");
        header.getCell(3).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(4).setCellValue("content");
        header.getCell(4).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(5).setCellValue("department");
        header.getCell(5).setCellStyle(style);



        header.createCell(6).setCellValue("status");
        header.getCell(6).setCellStyle(style);




        header.createCell(7).setCellValue("contacting_date");
        header.getCell(7).setCellStyle(style);


        header.createCell(8).setCellValue("house_Number");
        header.getCell(8).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(9).setCellValue("Urgency");
        header.getCell(9).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(10).setCellValue("is_inspector");
        header.getCell(10).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(11).setCellValue("inspectorStatus");
        header.getCell(11).setCellStyle(style);



        header.createCell(12).setCellValue("stringDate");
        header.getCell(12).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(13).setCellValue("openedBy");
        header.getCell(13).setCellStyle(style);

        // create data rows
        int rowCount = 1;

        for (Contacting Contacting : listContactings) {
            HSSFRow aRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            aRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(Contacting.getContacting_id());
            aRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(Contacting.getUser_id());
            aRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(Contacting.getSubject());
            aRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(Contacting.getLocation());
            aRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(Contacting.getContent());
            aRow.createCell(5).setCellValue(Contacting.getdepartment());
            aRow.createCell(6).setCellValue(Contacting.getStatus());
            aRow.createCell(7).setCellValue(Contacting.getContacting_date());
            aRow.createCell(8).setCellValue(Contacting.getHouse_Number());
            aRow.createCell(9).setCellValue(Contacting.getUrgency());
            aRow.createCell(10).setCellValue(Contacting.getIs_inspector());
            aRow.createCell(11).setCellValue(Contacting.getInspectorStatus());
            aRow.createCell(12).setCellValue(Contacting.getStringDate());
            aRow.createCell(13).setCellValue(Contacting.getOpenedBy());



        }
    }
}
```

I think that the problem in the library using but i try many versions and many ways to use it but i always get errors.

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this dependency and execute

> mvn clean install

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And i highly recommend that when you start to use maven as dependency resolver, continue using it and don't mix libraries from your own and maven, because you will find problems in the future.

Try to execute with that version, and we will see the exception, maybe we need to exclude some jar from the poi dependency because is already included

Comment: I try it first  remove the library and than paste this but i do maven clean and after maven install and get the error again

Comment: @user5993555 where is the error? in your original question?

Comment: Failed to execute goal on project SpringMvcJdbcTemplate: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.codejava.spring:SpringMvcJdbcTemplate:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.poi:poi:pom:3.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Comment: @user5993555 I think your problem is just related with your LAN connection, do you have some proxy? firewall? try also to comment all repositories you have defined into your pom.xml. Also have a look to the settings.xml maybe you have some net restriction. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334394/could-not-transfer-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-pluginpom2

Comment: Error reading file C:\Users\LA\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.9\poi-3.9.jar
C:\Users\LA\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.9\poi-3.9.jar (‏‏למערכת אין אפשרות לאתר את הקובץ שצוין)

Comment: Thats because you are not able to download the jar from maven repositories, check pom.xml and settings.xml file

Comment: i dont have settings.xml i just have web.xml but i have firewall  what i have to check and where?

Comment: C:\Users\LA\.m2\settings.xml here is your settings of maven.

Comment: If you use maven you have this file, try to find it with the file search engine,  the name is "settings.xml"

Comment: I dont find it i find just maven-settings file but with jar or pom end

Comment: If you are using maven, you HAVE this file, maybe is hidden by your OS as hidden files, try to be sure all files are visible, is an option for folders view. But trust me, you have this file, and if you deleted you will have to create again or reinstall maven.

Comment: i still dont find it can you explain me how to do it

Comment: you can follow this guide, https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html, is quite complete and original from maven