# configure proxy for eclipse to create maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I work in a company, we use java and Ide is Eclipse. But I had the first problem of configuring the proxy for eclipse when creating a new maven project it though I followed the instructions of the article below. But when I need to copy to the .m2 folder of ubuntu do not see that folder so now what do I need? Thanks
Here is the link I made to the error that I am having

https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/set-proxy-for-maven-in-eclipse.html

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
Any answers can help me, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.7.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334394/could-not-transfer-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-pluginpom2)

Comment: How do others in your company solve this?