# Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, netbeans-11

I am trying to run my first project "Calculator" on netbeans-11 july version and it gives this error -
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.0: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.5.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.196.215] failed**: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

my pom.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>Calculator</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>
```

how to resolve this ?

Comment: what version of java/JDK are you using?

Comment: Maven cannot connect to maven central. Are you behind a company firewall?

Comment: @Santos my java version is 12.0.1

Comment: I have allowed the netbeans app through all firewalls. but still it is showing the same error.

Comment: Also, if you are working for a company, please check if you have added settings.xml in your .m2 local (C:\Users\*****\.m2\repository) with proper maven central URL and other details. If not then please add it with the proper maven central URL(better to ask your peers to share it).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, make sure your editor have finished downloading all Maven requirementents, also try to update your project under de Maven menu. Finally, make sure you are not behind a proxy, if that is the case, configure your settings.xml like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15335792/6173572).