# maven dependency issue in VDI machine

Tags: maven

I am facing below issue.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.2.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.airtelbank.merchant.settlement.feeder:apb-merchant-settlement-feeder:0.0.12: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.airtelbank.merchant.settlement.feeder:apb-merchant-settlement-feeder:0.0.12 (\\10.5.0.253\rdsh_dev_ind\b0218163\Desktop\code\merchant-settlement-feeder\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.airtelbank.merchant.settlement.feeder:apb-merchant-settlement-feeder:0.0.12: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

if any body face past. please help how to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.7.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334394/could-not-transfer-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-pluginpom2)

Comment: @juzraai The transfer is given with https..so this is unrelated.

Comment: The problem is `Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org` this means you have network/firewall/proxy error...that you are not allowed to access internet...or this special host...