# Pom.xml error while importing spring boot starter project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am downloading a project from Spring Initializr and pasting it to Intellij idea.
This issue keeps persisting

Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom ProxyInfo{host='123.45.6.78', userName='null', port=80, type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'}

My Pom.xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rooms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rooms</name>
    <description>Chatting room</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What i tried:

1. editing the settings.xml file according to this thread [Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.7.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334394/could-not-transfer-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-pluginpom2)
2. deleting .m2 folder in maven
3. Invalidate caches and restart

I have seen a lot of stackoverflow posts but sadly none of them seem to work.
How to resolve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: So you are behind a proxy and using http instead of https cause central is https only.

Comment: Clicking that link brought up the file in question in the browser; therefore, it's your network configuration.

Comment: I am having the same error .. :(

Answer (score 1):

Since January 15, 2020 maven central no longer supports HTTP, in favor of HTTPS. Consequently, spring repositories switched to HTTPS as well

Check this link for [setting proxies for maven build](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

Restart your Intellij

Answer (score 0):

Please create a file as "settings.xml" under "C:\Users<your_named_folder>.m2".
Then put the followings on "settings.xml". Save it.
Then delete everything from ".m2" folder and build the project by "mvn clean install" command. It should work.

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>anupam.com</id>
      <name>anupam</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The advise https://stackoverflow.com/a/63533677/8512173 helped me. I only started use anupam.com in settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

First check if your jdk/jre is has correct version. In my case jdk was 1.7 and It was expecting 1.8 or higher.

```
>mvn -e clean install log message


[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.10/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.10.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.kamdham:kamdham:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.10/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.10.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.kamdham:kamdham:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.10/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.10.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.kamdham:kamdham:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\RAVI_WORKSPACE\kamdham\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.kamdham:kamdham:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.10/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.10.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10: Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.10/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.10.pom
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1150)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:916)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.10/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.10.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1150)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:916)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.10/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.10.pom
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1150)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:916)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.10/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.10.pom
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1250)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1150)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:916)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException (Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException (Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert (SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute (MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1005)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1162)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1150)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:916)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:377)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```